Approximation Error on Arc Length of Quadratic Bezier curve
Given a quadratic Bezier curve defined by:
$$ B(t) = (1-t)^2P_0 + 2t(1-t)P_1 + t^2P_2 $$
The arc length $ s(t) $ from $0$ to $ t $ is:
$$ s(t) = \int_0^t |B'(τ)| dτ. $$
It's known that the arc length is hard to compute, and many numerical methods including the Gaussian quadrature are used to solve it.
I also came up with an heuristic formula $\tilde s(t)$ to approximate it. The intuition is as follows:
Consider the linear Lagrange interpolation $f(t)$ of $s$ at $t=0,1$: $f(t)=tl,$ where $l=s(1)$ is the total length of the Bezier curve. The error formula is given by:
$$
s(t)-tl=-\frac{1}{2}s''(\xi)(1-t)t,
$$
where $\xi \in (0,1)$ depends on $t$. In other words,
$$
s(t)=-\frac{1}{2}s''(\xi)(1-t)t+tl.
$$
Here is the heuristic part: because $tl$ interpolates $s(t)$ at $t=0,1,$ we can guess intuitively that $\xi$ is around $t=\frac{0+1}{2}=0.5$. So we use the formula
$$
\tilde s(t)=-\frac{1}{2}s''(0.5)(1-t)t+tl.
$$
to approximate $s(t)$. And the error is given by
$$
|\tilde s(t)-s(t)|=\frac{1}{2}(1-t)t\cdot |s''(\xi)-s''(0.5)|.
$$
The numerical result is pretty good actually. I set $|P_2-P_0|=300$, and the angle between $P_1-P_0$ and $P_2 -P_1$ to be $\varphi=\pi/6$ but let the length of $P_1-P_0$ and $P_2-P_1$ vary. Then the maximal error never exceed $0.2$.
My question is how to derive a good error bound in terms of $|P_1-P_0|, |P_2-P_1|, \varphi$ so that the bound could be put into practical use. I mean given an error $\epsilon$ and I restrict $\varphi<\pi/6$, how long can $|P_1-P_0|, |P_2-P_1|$ be so that $|\tilde s(t) - s(t)|<\epsilon$.
My attempt: first we can start by calculating $s''(t)$. Note that $s'(t) = |B'(t)|$.
$$ 
s''(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \langle B'(t), B'(t) \rangle^\frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{\langle B''(t), B'(t)\rangle}{|B'(t)|}=|B''(t)|\cos \beta (t),
$$
where $\beta(t)$ is the angle between $B''(t)$ and $B'(t)$. We also note that $B(t)$ is a quadratic Bezier curve so $B''(t)$ is constant, namely $B''(t) = B''(0)=2(P_2 - P_1) - 2(P_1 - P_0)=2P_2-4P_1+2P_0$. So
$$
s''(t)=|B''(0)|\cos\beta(t).
$$
As a result, the error becomes
$$
|\tilde s(t)-s(t)|=\frac{1}{2}(1-t)t\cdot |s''(\xi)-s''(0.5)| \\
= \frac{1}{2}(1-t)t\cdot |B''(0)|\cdot |\cos \beta(\xi) - \cos \beta(0.5)| \\
\leq \frac{1}{2}(1-t)t\cdot |B''(0)|\cdot |\beta(\xi) - \beta (0.5)|,
$$
here we used the mean value theorm $|\cos x - \cos y| = |-\sin \eta \cdot (x-y)| \leq |x-y|$.
To proceed, we note that $|\beta(\xi) - \beta (0.5)|\leq |\beta(0)-\beta(1)| = |\varphi|$, which is a very loose bound because $\xi$ could be very close to $0.5$ in experiment. The visualization of the geometry relation is attached in the end.
As a result, I obtained
$$
|\tilde s(t)-s(t)| \leq \frac{1}{2}(1-t)t\cdot |B''(0)|\cdot |\beta(\xi) - \beta (0.5)| \\
\leq  \frac{1}{2}(1-t)t\cdot |B''(0)| \cdot |\varphi| = O(|\varphi|). 
$$
So when the angle between $P_1-P_0$ and $P_2 - P_1$ approches zero i.e. the the control points almost lie in the same line, the formula is accurate.
However this result is useless in practice because the inequality $|\beta(\xi) - \beta (0.5)|\leq |\varphi|$ is too loose! The order of $|\beta(\xi) - \beta (0.5)|$ could be $0.005$ while $\varphi = 0.5$. I can only get some trivial conditions using this result, e.g. given $\epsilon = 0.01$, if $|P_1 - P_0| < 1, \varphi < \pi / 6$ then $|\tilde s(t) - s(t)|<\epsilon$. I guess a more accurate bound on $|\beta(\xi) - \beta (0.5)|$ can really help! But it's usually hard to get the $\xi$ in the interpolation error formula so I'm stuck here.


The arc length of a quadratic Bézier curve can be computed exactly; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854907/calculate-the-length-of-a-segment-of-a-quadratic-bezier

@lhf Thank you for your information, it is helpful! However there are some reasons the exact formula of the arc length can't be used directly for me, because I also want to be able to solve the inverse problem $s(t)=S$ quickly, given any $S\in [0, l]$ to find $t\in[0,1]$. A typical way to solve it is using the Newton iteration or bisection method once the exact value of $s(t)$ is computed, but it's quite slow. My motivation of the approximation also includes the ability of solving $\tilde s(t)=S$ quickly and the presented $\tilde s(t)$ is a quadratic function whose roots can be found quickly.
